# Is the device Beca uses in Pitch Perfect 3 a real musical device?

Tags: realism, props, pitch-perfect

In the Pitch Perfect 3, Beca creates sounds "Ah~ Oh~" with this loop pedal device that don't have labels. I don't know what's name and I haven't been able to find anything by searching for it online. Is this a real device? And who is the manufacturer of this?

[image]
[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: I haven’t found a current production looper the looks like that. It might be that the pedal used for filming was not a looper and they just used a random pedal as the prop.

Comment: I don't recognise it specifically - but there's an oval piece of tape over where a name might be… & I do love the detail of the bit of gaffa holding the wireless dongle in place… even if they didn't plug the power supply in [we can assume it's running on batteries, I guess] ;)

Comment: Play with Pororo, are you asking if this **type** of device is real or if this **specific model** of device is real? @Paulie_D's answer addresses the former while the comments above address the latter.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's a device called a **looper pedal**.

There are many varieties available.

Comment: Beat me to it - [here's a whole swathe of them](https://www.andertons.co.uk/guitar-dept/guitar-pedals/looper-pedals?pageNumber=1) Popularity much increased over the past few years by Ed Sheeran - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX2eJsj9MiQ

Comment: @Tetsujin: Talking about Ed Sheeran + loop, I really enjoy this "I see fire" performance : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUx9tNzpbbs 

And almost 15 years ago, I was blown away by Dub FX : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F6EoMdn95E

Comment: hey May I ask a question? I wanna this device, so is it real product? And I wanna know about this specific model of device